# Has anyone tried getting this signature pad to work in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm going way out on the crazy ask limb on this one I'm sure. Has any one made this signature app work in Google App Maker?

https://github.com/github.com/szimek/signature_pad

I've made a paid version of the one from the folks at "App Maker University" work. But it's got some buggy issues when it comes to data source relations in one to many relations. I've done some work around's with  the "AMU" version. In the end it's still glitchier than I'd like (signatures not updating or saving, and some overwriting of older signatures). After hours of experimenting I'm at a loss on how to get it to play nice.

Just wondering if this github version would be any cleaner and if someone has a working version in app maker I'd love to play with it.

Comment: I'm still in the process of integrating it. It will take some time but I will update the thread once I'm done, in case this have no answer yet.

Comment: Awesome! I look forward to seeing the results.